# CodeIgniter: Show a "Loading..." page while the Controller does its operations

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a Controller who made some operations (third-party API calls, DB operations, etc) and it tooks 5-6 seconds to complete them. When completed it calls this view: $this->load->view('user/catalog', $params);

I do not want to let my user wait 5-6 seconds in front of a white screen, I would like to show him a "Loading" screen in order to let he know that has to wait a while and then he will see the results.

I know this is nothing complex to do if operations would be made in Ajax. But this is not the case:

user goes here: mysite.com/catalog --> controller "Catalog" starts doing all the operations, and when completed shows the view "/user/catalog".

I tried to add a $this->load->view('user/loading'); call right at the start of the Catalog controller, but the result is that after 5-6 seconds the user sees both the "loading" and the "catalog" view one after the other.

Any idea how to do this?

Thanks

Comment: Just like you said, this should be solvable by using AJAX. Loads the loading screen and then in the background, fire off an AJAX request that will fetch the necessary data, then modify the DOM to display the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have not tried it, but yes you can do it through server side also instead of using ajax by using flush() and ob_flush().
Please refer to the below sample code, only for understanding, and go through the below links to give it a try:-
https://www.php.net/ob_flush

```
<?php
header( 'Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8' );
echo 'Begin ...<br />';
for( $i = 0 ; $i < 10 ; $i++ )
{
    echo $i . '<br />';
    flush();
    ob_flush();
    sleep(1);
}
echo 'End ...<br />';
?>
```